# Ubuntu MATE 21.04 + ZFS + encryption

Tags: encryption, zfs

So I nuked my laptop and loaded Ubuntu MATE 21.04 daily. During install I choose ZFS + encryption. Because I could ;).

So what did I just do? Can someone give me some details about how this works underneath? Did I get ZFS native encryption? Or is it Luks+ZFS? And what is all encrypted now? Root, boot, swap?

Also my laptop has an SSD and a harddisk. Is it possible to get ZFS + encryption on the harddisk as well, without putting in a passphrase all the time. Maybe with a keyfile? Or are there better options?

Comment: Is [this ZFS tutorial](https://www.unixtutorial.org/getting-started-with-zfs-ubuntu-20-04/) of any help?

Comment: Sorry, I knew all of this already. I'm also running a Z2 raid on my mediaserver. This laptop is just to play with and see if I can learn some new stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZFS on Linux supports ZFS native encryption; as of 20.04 desktop you could modify the install script to make the root pool use ZFS native encryption, so I presume that's what's happening when you select the ZFS Encryption GUI option in 21.04.

You can check the status of encryption across all of your pools by getting the relevant encryption properties:

```
zfs get -p encryption,keystatus,keysource
```

As far as what is encrypted and how the datasets are configured: the Ubuntu ZFS installer creates two pools. The first is a very limited featureset bpool at /boot, and a fuller root dataset (rpool) with multiple sub-datasets, and only rpool is encrypted if ZFS encryption is enabled.

Remember that `zpool list` will show you what zpools are on the system, and `zfs list` will you show all of the datasets

You can check what is actually happening and what pools are created by peeking at the file at `/usr/share/ubiquity/zsys-setup` when booted from the installer CD.

You can certainly use a keyfile for the harddisk, and you can even create a systemd service file to unlock it automatically during boot (which is safe to do, since the dataset that holds the keyfile won't be decrypted until you type your password in for the disk encryption). Arch Linux guide (but still totally applicable) here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#Unlock_at_boot_time:_systemd

Comment: Thank you for the info. I made it work. It took me a little time to find out that the zfs executable location is different in Arch than in Ubuntu. I had to change /usr/bin/zfs to /usr/sbin/zfs.